str_detect() function unable to match the exact pattern of the input as a part of a user-defined function
I have a data frame (in long format), that has personal ID, ICD codes, diagnosis date of 1000's of individuals. I want to write a function that can run over this data frame and generate few variables with 1 and 0 (without changing the actual structure of the data).
I am using the following codes to do this:
library(tidyverse)

create_icd_flags <- function(df) {
  
  icd_patterns <- c("^DO23", "^DO264", "^DO85", "^DO86", "^DO98", "^630\\d*$", "^635\\d*$", "^670\\d*$")

  df %>%
    mutate(ICD_code = str_trim(ICD_code)) %>%
    
    group_by(PID) %>%
    mutate(
      disease = case_when(
        any(map_lgl(icd_patterns, ~ any(str_detect(ICD_code, .x)))) ~ 1,
        TRUE ~ 0  
      )
    ) %>%
    ungroup()
}

df_with_flags <- create_icd_flags(df)

But the create_icd_flags () function, actually matching/detecting many unwanted pattern (such as DR630, DO635, Y670, 87635, and so on) in case of the numeric codes 630, 635 and 670, and a result those mismatched rows are assigned with 1, even though they should have 0 for the disease variable. I want to assign 1 for these numeric codes which start with either 630, 635 or 670 (in addition to the other codes).
N.B: Its possible they may have numerous sub codes such as 6300A, 63502, 6701C, and so on for which I want to assign 1.

Is it safe to assume that ^ in "^D023" is used in the regex meaning of 'begins with', and that the data in column is "D023" & etc, such that `strsplit("^DO23", split='D')[[1]][2]
[1] "O23"?

It would help to have a minimum working example of data and show what you would like the output to look like (e.g., which codes should be included). See the suggestions for writing an R question.
